# How to create two commands with the same name but different number of parameters and style

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, tkz-euclide

I want to define a command with the same name, but a different number of parameters.
I want the call \tkzDrawAltitude(A,M,B) be equivalent to \tkzDrawAltitude(A,B)(M) in a document.

I'm considering something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\makeatletter
\def\tkzDrawAltitude{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\tkz@Altitude}{\tkz@Altitude[]}}
\def\tkz@Altitude[#1](#2,#3)(#4){% 
\begingroup
    \tkzUProjection(#2,#3)(#4)
    \tkzDrawSLine[add= 0 and 0,/tkzdrawl/.cd,#1](#4,tkzPointResult)
\endgroup
}
\def\tkz@Altitude[#1](#2,#3,#4){%
\begingroup
    \tkzUProjection(#2,#4)(#3)
    \tkzDrawSLine[add= 0 and 0,/tkzdrawl/.cd,#1](#3,tkzPointResult)
\endgroup
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{Command (arg,arg)(arg)}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[ymin=-0.5,ymax=6.6,xmin=-0.5,xmax=7.5]
\tkzClip
\tkzSetUpPoint[color=black,fill=white,size=3]
\tkzDefPoints{3/5/A,1/0/B,7/0/C}
\tkzDefMidPoint(B,C)\tkzGetPoint{M}

\tkzDrawAltitude(A,B)(M)\tkzGetPoint{N}%Command here

\tkzDefPointBy[projection=onto B--C](A)\tkzGetPoint{H}
\tkzDrawSegments(A,B B,C C,A A,H)
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,M,N,H)
\tkzLabelPoints[left](N)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](A)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](B,H,M,C)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\section{Command (arg,arg,arg)}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[ymin=-0.5,ymax=6.6,xmin=-0.5,xmax=7.5]
\tkzClip
\tkzSetUpPoint[color=black,fill=white,size=3]
\tkzDefPoints{3/5/A,1/0/B,7/0/C}
\tkzDefMidPoint(B,C)\tkzGetPoint{M}

\tkzDrawAltitude(A,M,B)\tkzGetPoint{N}%Command here

\tkzDefPointBy[projection=onto B--C](A)\tkzGetPoint{H}
\tkzDrawSegments(A,B B,C C,A A,H)
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,M,N,H)
\tkzLabelPoints[left](N)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](A)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](B,H,M,C)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, I'm not sure what you want to do in your code but speaking about your request: I doubt that what you're asking is even possible, how could you have two commands that have the exact same name but take different arguments? How would the engine distinguish between the two? But even if it was, what would the advantage be? You would be confused too, I think.

Comment: Just to clear up things: your question is that the call `\tkzDrawAltitude(A,M,B)` be equivalent to `\tkzDrawAltitude(A,B)(M)`?

Comment: Just to clear up things: it could be that you really want a unique command with two mandatory  arguments plus an optional argument? The latex commands can take optional arguments and make conditionally different things, but two commands with the same name is a contradiction in its own terms except if they are defined in different groups or environments (e.g. `\def\foo{foo}{\def\foo{baz}\foo} \foo`)

Comment: Thank you for your interest and reply.
Because the new update tkz-euclide package has the command to keep the name intact but change the structure parameters. Currently I have a document containing the old \tkzDrawAltitude (A, B) (M) and \tkzDrawAltitude (A, M, B) structure. This data is quite a lot, can not be edited each command, I would like a way to customize the tkzDrawAltitude command to run simultaneously in 2 structures.

Answer (score 2):

You can redefine `\tkzDrawAltitude` to have a mandatory argument in parentheses, with at most two commas in it, and an optional argument in parentheses.

If the optional argument does not appear, we assume the `(A,M,B)` syntax has been used. With `\SplitArgument{2}{,}` we'll get `#1` as `{A}{M}{B}`, so we pass it to `\auxA@tkzDrawAltitude` that does `\saved@tkzDrawAltitude(A,M,B)`.

Otherwise we assume the `(A,B)(M)` syntax; in this case `#1` would be `{A}{B}{-NoValue-}` and `#2` will be `M`, so we pass them to `\auxB@tkzDrawAltitude` which has four arguments: it ignores the third one and places the fourth in the middle, so calling again `\saved@tkzDrawAltitude(A,M,B)`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\makeatletter
% save the command in tkz-euclide
\let\saved@tkzDrawAltitude\tkzDrawAltitude
% carefully redefine it
\RenewDocumentCommand{\tkzDrawAltitude}{
  O{}
  >{\SplitArgument{2}{,}}r()
  d()
}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#3}
   {% new syntax (A,M,B)
    \auxA@tkzDrawAltitude{#1}#2%
   }
   {% old syntax (A,B)(M)
    \auxB@tkzDrawAltitude{#1}#2{#3}%
   }
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\auxA@tkzDrawAltitude}{mmmm}{%
  \saved@tkzDrawAltitude[#1](#2,#3,#4)%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\auxB@tkzDrawAltitude}{mmmmm}{%
  \saved@tkzDrawAltitude[#1](#2,#5,#3)%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Command (arg,arg)(arg)}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[ymin=-0.5,ymax=6.6,xmin=-0.5,xmax=7.5]
\tkzClip
\tkzSetUpPoint[color=black,fill=white,size=3]
\tkzDefPoints{3/5/A,1/0/B,7/0/C}
\tkzDefMidPoint(B,C)\tkzGetPoint{M}

\tkzDrawAltitude[draw=red](A,B)(M)\tkzGetPoint{N}%Command here

\tkzDefPointBy[projection=onto B--C](A)\tkzGetPoint{H}
\tkzDrawSegments(A,B B,C C,A A,H)
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,M,N,H)
\tkzLabelPoints[left](N)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](A)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](B,H,M,C)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\section{Command (arg,arg,arg)}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[ymin=-0.5,ymax=6.6,xmin=-0.5,xmax=7.5]
\tkzClip
\tkzSetUpPoint[color=black,fill=white,size=3]
\tkzDefPoints{3/5/A,1/0/B,7/0/C}
\tkzDefMidPoint(B,C)\tkzGetPoint{M}

\tkzDrawAltitude[draw=red](A,M,B)\tkzGetPoint{N}%Command here

\tkzDefPointBy[projection=onto B--C](A)\tkzGetPoint{H}
\tkzDrawSegments(A,B B,C C,A A,H)
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,M,N,H)
\tkzLabelPoints[left](N)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](A)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](B,H,M,C)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

#### Output without `[draw=red]`

[image]

#### Output with `[draw=red]`

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: I ask you to debug for help if you add the option below you will get an error
\tkzDrawAltitude[draw=red](A,M,B)\tkzGetPoint{N}

Comment: @AnhTuấnTrần Fixed by adding the provision of an initial optional argument.

Comment: Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is sufficient to count the amount of comma-separated elements within `\tkzDrawAltitude`'s first `)`-delimited argument and fork accordingly.

For counting elements of a comma-list you can, e.g, use expl3's `\clist_count:n`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}[2020/03/18]

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\CommaListElementCount}{}{\clist_count:n}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\tkzDrawAltitude{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\tkz@Altitude}{\tkz@Altitude[]}}%
\renewcommand*\tkz@Altitude{}%
\def\tkz@Altitude[#1](#2){%
  \ifnum\CommaListElementCount{#2}<3 %
  \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
  {\tkz@@Altitude}{\tkz@@@Altitude}[{#1}](#2)%
}%
\@ifdefinable\tkz@@Altitude{%
  \def\tkz@@Altitude[#1](#2,#3)(#4){% 
    \begingroup
    \tkzUProjection(#2,#3)(#4)%
    \tkzDrawSLine[add= 0 and 0,/tkzdrawl/.cd,#1](#4,tkzPointResult)
    \endgroup
  }%
  %Alternatively: 
  %\def\tkz@@Altitude[#1](#2,#3)(#4){\tkz@@@Altitude[{#1}]({#2},{#4},{#3})}%
}%
\@ifdefinable\tkz@@@Altitude{%
  \def\tkz@@@Altitude[#1](#2,#3,#4){%
    \begingroup
    \tkzUProjection(#2,#4)(#3)
    \tkzDrawSLine[add= 0 and 0,/tkzdrawl/.cd,#1](#3,tkzPointResult)
    \endgroup
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Command (arg,arg)(arg)}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[ymin=-0.5,ymax=6.6,xmin=-0.5,xmax=7.5]
\tkzClip
\tkzSetUpPoint[color=black,fill=white,size=3]
\tkzDefPoints{3/5/A,1/0/B,7/0/C}
\tkzDefMidPoint(B,C)\tkzGetPoint{M}

\tkzDrawAltitude(A,B)(M)\tkzGetPoint{N}%Command here

\tkzDefPointBy[projection=onto B--C](A)\tkzGetPoint{H}
\tkzDrawSegments(A,B B,C C,A A,H)
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,M,N,H)
\tkzLabelPoints[left](N)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](A)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](B,H,M,C)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\section{Command (arg,arg,arg)}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[ymin=-0.5,ymax=6.6,xmin=-0.5,xmax=7.5]
\tkzClip
\tkzSetUpPoint[color=black,fill=white,size=3]
\tkzDefPoints{3/5/A,1/0/B,7/0/C}
\tkzDefMidPoint(B,C)\tkzGetPoint{M}

\tkzDrawAltitude(A,M,B)\tkzGetPoint{N}%Command here

\tkzDefPointBy[projection=onto B--C](A)\tkzGetPoint{H}
\tkzDrawSegments(A,B B,C C,A A,H)
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,M,N,H)
\tkzLabelPoints[left](N)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](A)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](B,H,M,C)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much!